# knife with encrypted client key?

Tags: chef-infra, knife

Is it possible to use knife with an encrypted client key on a workstation?
It seems to be asking for the client key a *lot* (tens of times) during a berks install for example and it fails randomly sometimes.

So my question would be if it was possible to set the client key password in the knife.rb some way, that could be read from input when that file is parsed for example?

Thanks,

Comment: Any output that you could add to your question?

Comment: Ah, are you talking about `knife ssh` and you want to log into multiple servers? You might look for the term "ssh agent" then.

Comment: No, I'm looking to encrypt the client key for chef used to identify the workstation with the chef server

Comment: I would say that's out of scope for chef / `knife`. I would say encrypt your home directory or only the file using some dedicated software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not supported. The last time someone asked I recommended they look into patching Chef to support using key data from ssh-agent, but I never heard back from them.

Comment: coderanger, you seem to be all around chef questions on stackoverflow, are you an opscode employee?

Comment: No I am not an employee of Chef Software.